# Dynamic Menu From JSON Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new to angularjs, i want to display dynamic menu from json array.

```js
{
"Pages": [{
 "PageId": 1,
 "PageTitle": "Home",
 "PageContent": "Home Page Content",
 "MenuType": "MainMenu",
 "ParentMenu": null,
 "PageStatus": "Active",
 "PageType": true
}, {
 "PageId": 2,
 "PageTitle": "About",
 "PageContent": "about content",
 "MenuType": "SubMenu",
 "ParentMenu": Home,
 "PageStatus": "Active",
 "PageType": true
}, {
 "PageId": 3,
 "PageTitle": "Contact",
 "PageContent": "Contact Us Content",
 "MenuType": "MainMenu",
 "ParentMenu": null,
 "PageStatus": "Active",
 "PageType": true
}]
}
```

I want menu to be like this:

```
- Home
  - About
- Contact
```

Please help me with answer.. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the code around the json array? html and js? is it possible that the example snippet runs at the snippet editor?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your template look? The controller? The info you provided isn't enough

Comment: You need to change the JSON array format. Sub-menu array should be inside Main-menu array. for example. 'About' should be inside 'Home' object

Comment: How many levels is the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will iterate over your menu and convert it to nested html lists that you can attach to an element in your webpage.

```js
const menu = {
  "Pages": [
    { "PageId": 1, "PageTitle": "Home",       "ParentMenu": null },
    { "PageId": 2, "PageTitle": "About",      "ParentMenu": "Home" },
    { "PageId": 3, "PageTitle": "Contact",    "ParentMenu": null },
    { "PageId": 4, "PageTitle": "Our Story",  "ParentMenu": "About" },
    { "PageId": 5, "PageTitle": "Our Future", "ParentMenu": "About" },
  ]
}

// abstracted way to create an element
const createElement = (type, className, text) => {
  const el = document.createElement(type)
  el.className = className
  if (text) {
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
  }
  return el
}

// print the menu as a tree
const createMenu = (menu, parentName = null, level = 0) =>
  menu.reduce((ul, item) => {
    if (item.ParentMenu === parentName) {
      const li = createElement(`li`, `menu__item`, item.PageTitle)
      ul.appendChild(li)
      // recursively call itself changing the parentName to the current PageTitle
      const children = createMenu(menu, item.PageTitle, level+1)
      if (children.childNodes.length) {
        li.appendChild(children)
      }
    }
    return ul
  }, createElement(`ul`, `menu__list level--${level}`))

const app = document.querySelector(`#app`)
app.appendChild(
  createMenu(menu.Pages, null)
)
console.log(app.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @synthet1c.. i want that menus to be like this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h  could you please help me out?